# Insert Data into middle of range

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have the following model

```
public class DailyRoutine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Scenario:**
When is created at initial time with 5 records which means 5 entries are entered for each day. Take an example May 1 to May 5 of 2017. Description have any string.

User can add a new record in the middle so that the following records should be moved and changed to next days.

**Expected Output:**
Example, user can give a date and description in input and submit. If the input date is '5/3/2017' (May 3), the entry should be added after May 2 record and the existing May 3 record changed to May 4, May 4 to May 5 etc. So the out is like May 1 to May 6 and the given input is updated on May 3.

Please help me to this with out degrading performance

Comment: Did you already try anything?

Comment: What approach have you tried?

Comment: How do you store these models in your viewmodel (presuming MVVM)? You should probably have a `List<DailyRoutine>`, or something like that, somewhere in your code. Do you read these entries from your SQL DB each time you need them? You should provide more code and show what you already came up with. In most cases it is as trivial as doing a `.Insert([Index], new DailiyRoutine())` on your `List<DailyRoutine>`. You'll also need to use the `ORDER BY` keyword in your SQL query when reading these entries to get them in the right order from the DB. SQL doesn't order your rows as you insert them.

Comment: @r41n this is in webapi. Yes i get you for the ordering and i can also thought that. But anyway i need to update the existing dates to the next date. So as per yours my idea is , just update the entries from the given date using loop and then add the new entry in the last. All these should have order field or we can use order by date. correct?

Comment: @Akhil, Romano Zumbé is right, so is his approach. If there's no other way for you to avoid changing all your `DailyRoutine` instances, than his answer is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach will work:

```
List<DailyRoutine> d = new List<DailyRoutine>()
{
    new DailyRoutine() { Date = new DateTime(2017, 7, 1)},
    new DailyRoutine() { Date = new DateTime(2017, 7, 2)},
    new DailyRoutine() { Date = new DateTime(2017, 7, 3)},
    new DailyRoutine() { Date = new DateTime(2017, 7, 4)},
    new DailyRoutine() { Date = new DateTime(2017, 7, 5)}
};

DailyRoutine newDr = new DailyRoutine() { Date = new DateTime(2017, 7, 2) };
DailyRoutine oldDr = d.Where(dr => dr.Date == newDr.Date).FirstOrDefault();

if (oldDr != null)
{
    int idx = d.IndexOf(oldDr);
    List<DailyRoutine> changeList = d.Where((dr, i) => i >= idx).ToList();

    foreach (DailyRoutine i in changeList)
    {
        i.Date = i.Date.AddDays(1);
    }

    d.Insert((int)idx, newDr);
}
else
{
    d.Add(newDr);
}
```

Comment: nice. will try this. But any performance degrade by using this insert method?  Please check the comment of  r41n also. Which one is more optimized way ?

Comment: This sure is not as fast as just inserting the new object. Every object with an equal or higher date needs to be touched. But that is one of your design requirements. Besides this, the run time increases linear with the object count (which is good). I thin r41n didn't take into account, that the items need to be modified.